# Where to set custom ClaimsPrincipal for all HttpRequests

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I'm porting older application to ASP.NET Core, that uses Windows Authentication (configured in IIS, resp. launchsetting.json).

I would like to override the authentication to use custom hardcoded ClaimsPrincipal, when running in developlement mode.

```
public class Startup
{
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {

       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       }
       app.UseMvc();    
   }
}
```

I'm not sure what is the correct place to set the identity and services/middleware configuration to use...

Comment: Have a look at the existing [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888859/asp-net-core-2-1-register-custom-claimsprincipal)

Comment: Co I should just use ClaimsTranformer even if I have unauthenticated requests and I want to make them authenticated? I thought that ClaimsTransformer is meant to jut add/remove claims from existing identity

Answer (score 2):

There’s the correct way to edit existing identity and it’s called claims transformation. Basically, we have to write a custom class that implements the IClaimsTransformation interface. Documentation doesn’t give much information about it but the most important thing is said – we need to clone the given identity.

In short, here’s how the process goes:

1. Clone current user identity
2. Add custom claims
3. Return cloned identity

   ```
   public class AddRolesClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
   {
       private readonly IUserService _userService; public class AddRolesClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
       {
           private readonly IUserService _userService;

           public AddRolesClaimsTransformation(IUserService userService)
   {

       _userService = userService;
   }

   public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
   {
       // Clone current identity
       var clone = principal.Clone();
       var newIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)clone.Identity;

       // Support AD and local accounts
       var nameId = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type ==
           ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier || c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
       if (nameId == null)
       {
           return principal;
       }

       // Get user from database
       var user = await _userService.GetByUserName(nameId.Value);
       if (user == null)
       {
           return principal;
       }

       // Add role claims to cloned identity
       foreach (var role in user.Roles)
       {
           var claim = new Claim(newIdentity.RoleClaimType, role.Name);
           newIdentity.AddClaim(claim);
       }

       return clone;
   } }
   ```

The final thing to do is to register claims transformation with dependency injection in the ConfigureServices() method of the Startup class.

```
services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, AddRolesClaimsTransformation>();
enter code here
```

Based on https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-adding-claims-to-existing-identity/

Answer (score 0):

Create middleware sets `HttpContext.User` to hardcoded `ClaimsPrincipal`

```
public class WindowsUserMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public WindowsUserMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim> { /* add claims */ };
        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "NonEmptyAuthType");

        httpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}

public static class WindowsUserMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseWindowsUser(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
        return applicationBuilder.UseMiddleware<WindowsUserMiddleware>();
    }

}
```

And use it in development mode only

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWindowsUser();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
app.UseMvc();
```